# How to return/terminate symfony2 response in function other than the requested action?

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm building a RESTful API using Symfony2, FOSRestBundle and an OAuth 2 server library.

For any given request, there are a number of possible responses and status codes that I can return to the client.

Take for example the process of getting a user:

```
<?php

class UserController extends CustomBaseController {


    /**
     * Get a user
     * @Get("/users", name="users_get")
     */
    public function getAction(Request $request) {

        // Ensure a valid access token is present
        $this->validAccessTokenOrExit();

        $user = $this->getUser();
        return $this->handleView($this->view($user, 200));

    }

}
```

Ideally I would like to have the validAccessTokenOrExit() function terminate the request and return the 401 status code with an appropriate message. This means I can handle authentication in this function and reuse it in several actions across the API.

However I can't seem to find a way of terminating the response from another function, and I always have to return a Response from the action called.

Are there any clean solutions to accomplish this or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

If you throw an exception that has the interface `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface` (`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException` for example) with the status code set (first parameter as 401 for `HttpException`) it will be handled by the HttpKernel in the way that you are expecting.

For example..

```
throw new HttpException(401, 'Something went wrong');
```

.. will be turned into a response with 401 as the status code.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. The problem with throwing an exception is that on it's own, I couldn't return a response such as: 

{
    "code": 401,
    "error: "Invalid access token" 
}

Throwing an exception is probably the way I'll have to go, but was really looking for a way to have fine control over returning a response from any controller function with any format I specify. Any additional ideas that might help with this?

Comment: What do you mean by "with any format I specify"? If you are just wanting to be able to include a message then you just need to do a little bit of messing with the fosrestbundle's config (if that's the issue let me know and I will update my answer), if something else (you mention format too, so I'm not sure) I would need more information but I'm pretty sure it can be done.

Comment: Structure is perhaps a better word to use than format. By structure I mean the 'data structure'. Really I'm just looking for a way to encode an array with the fields I need and return the response somewhere other than the called action. Your suggestion of throwing an Exception does terminate the response but I can only submit a simple message whereas I'll need to add more fields to the returned data. FOSRestBundle does come with a solution for formatting exception response but figuring out how to use it was an uphill battle, so I was hoping to find a native Symfony2 way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->createAccessDeniedException('message')` within a controller.

This will create `AccessDeniedException`, terminate the current request and return a `403`  with your message.

Answer (score 0):

I did faced this situation and for time being I call the terminating function with return. Return false from function when valid.

```
 if($r=$this->validAccessTokenOrExit()){ 
   return $r;
 }
```

Alternatively I use following two methods for redirecting or rendering a view form another function and terminating flow.

Redirection:

```
header('location:'. $this->generateUrl('deals_product_view', array('id' => 1)));
exit;
```

Rendering a view:

```
     $response = new Response();    
     $response->setContent($this->renderView($view_file, $params ));
     $response->send();
     exit;
```